# ZeroMQ (TCP) workaround for port forwarding

Tags: python, sockets, zeromq, p2p, pyzmq

I currently have a ZeroMQ peer to peer network I'm building using Python and PyZMQ. Currently the server listens with a REP TCP socket and connects directly to other peers listening on the same type of socket. This requires port forwarding for clients to get to the servers sadly though. Is there anyway to get around this? Can I do some kind of UDP discovery and then switch over to TCP? Or am I doomed to switch to a UDP style network to solve this problem?

Comment: Why does it require port forwarding? There's not enough concrete information here to understand what your problem is.  Perhaps you could post some code and indicate where its limitations are failing you?

Comment: Users will most likely be running the application from a NAT IP address. ZeroMQ and other TCP socket based communication can't reach to those servers without help, I undrstand that. Is there a way though to bootstrap the connection to punch through and connect up? Sorry if it isn't clear. I don't think code will really help here.

Comment: The code, or at least a diagram, will help to understand the network topology you're trying to accomplish.  For instance, "punch through and connect up" to what?  A known server?  Another client/peer?  How and why does one side bind and the other connect on the socket?  I can guess some of these details, but I'd rather know exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Here's the network diagram [IMAGE](https://imgur.com/fzRHKZg) Basically I would fire up my application and it would bind to my externally facing IP and listen for connections from other peers. If I am behind a cable modem or router that has issued me a local IP then the peer would try to connect to my server at the external IP and fail because I'm actually at the NAT'd IP and the router won't send the traffic through to me. Establishing the TCP connection from a peer acting as a client would fail.

Comment: OK, then you're snookered :) Your understanding of the limitations of TCP is the same as mine. There's no way to get to that internal computer without the router knowing how to forward that data, and that'd have to be set up at each router, through port forwarding.  If you don't require a *strictly* peer-to-peer topology, or you can guarantee some peers will be directly accessible by IPs and can function as super-nodes, then you can call out to those directly accessible servers and have communication flow through them. But you can't bind on an IP that the computer itself doesn't have.

Comment: I read somewhere (can't remember where now) that you can bootstrap the connection somehow with UDP and then swtich, but I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: For ZMQ or for generic TCP? If it's TCP, you'd almost have to achieve those types of shenanigans in the ZMQ internals, since there's no way (that I'm aware of) to set up a TCP connection and then pass it in to ZMQ, and that's what it would require.

Comment: K. Is [this article](http://hintjens.com/blog:32) perhaps where you read about this? Found by googling "zmq udp bootstrap".